# What is your preferred circuit simulator for high-performance analog/mixed signal?

Tags: spice, mixed-signal

I'm starting a new job and I've been using NI multisim in school, but I am trying to decide if I should learn a new spice simulator.

Not sure how to compare Multisim to something like LTspice which my boss likes to use. For reference I'll be doing a lot of mixed signal stuff, Op-amps, filters, buffers, ADC's, maybe some power supply circuits. Frequency ranges will probably be in the Mhz range.

My main concern is that multisim is not robust enough to handle higher level signal analysis (noise, distortion, etc...)

Comment: Micro-sim every time. LTSpice never.

Comment: I can put in a really good word for Cadence Spectre -- if you have the budget for something like ADE or Virtuoso.

Answer (score 2):

LTSpice uses standard SPICE deck format, and has been well-maintained by Linear (now Analog Devices) over the years. It is accurate and has a rich library of components (weighted heavily towards ADI / Linear's catalog of course.)

Some reading about how LTSpice works: [LTSpice Differentiation](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/spice-differentiation.html)

MicroCap is also good, supports standard SPICE models, has a more intuitive UI than LTSpice (something I consider LTSpice's weak point), and is now freeware. The latter point is kind of an issue as it isn't maintained anymore.

Moving off Multisim to LTSpice, and in the process gaining knowledge of SPICE decks, will be a marketable skill for you later regardless of which SPICE-based sim you ultimately decide upon. It will certainly be the case if your career focus is mixed-signal design.

That said, for quick-and-dirty small sims that you don't care about SPICE compatibility, Falstad works well. The ability to poke and prod the live simulation is something that's really useful (and slightly addictive.)

MORE: I'll add a plug for a textbook authored by frequent SE contributor @VerbalKint: [https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Mode-Power-Supplies-Second-Simulations/dp/0071823468](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468)

Comment: I don't entirely trust Falstead. I've had situations where Falstad completely did not match up with reality while LTSpice did. Still don't know why. Was a simple opamp oscillator that relied on hysteresis. Falstad  is fast though. LTSpice is unwieldly. Microcap eh? Looks like they shutdown so it's now free which is good but bad because it will become increasingly outdated.

Comment: LTSpice is compatible with most of PSpice syntax, even though some of the compatible commands aren't documented in LTSpice. Agreed that the user interface is clunky, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Totally agree. Wouldn't use Falstad as a sign-off tool.

Comment: Because I was bored, I created a couple of switching regulator designs, a voltage-control type and COT type in Falstad. Watching how the supply behaves as I alter the feedback network is kind of interesting, trading ripple for response for stability.

Comment: I somehow missed the MicroCap news.  Learning to ride a bike, first date, learning MicroCap, all key moments in the formative years.  I still compare every SCH cad platform to it's UI, and all others tend to fail (I'm talking to you, Altium).